# Cделать правильный запрос SQL

Tags: mysql

Есть 2 таблицы `products(id,product_name,price)` и `reviews(id,product_id,commentary)`.

Нужно получить `product_name`,`price` и `count(commentary)` по каждому товару.   Написал такой запрос

```
SELECT products.id
      ,products.product_name 
      , COUNT(reviews.commentary) as amount 
FROM products 
JOIN  reviews   
WHERE products.id = reviews.product_id  
GROUP by products.id
```

вроде бы правильно выбирает,но не показывает товары без комментариев

Comment: `left join` используйте, и условия соединения пишите там где соединяете, не надо его тащить в `where`. в группировке перечисляйте все группируемые поля, mysql хоть и прощает огрехи такие, но пишите корректный синтаксис.

Comment: спасибо большое